# Sending email with attached spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I prepared script to send automatic email with attached spreadsheet but it's converting file to pdf... How to fix this?

```
function sendEmails() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
 var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
 // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
 var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
 var message = row[1]; // Second column
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet'
var waiver = DriveApp.getFileById("1rXGktttzHH8fxx2GYGs2vGrFDF9RLyp7A8oE- 
 mpgX7k")
   var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.spreadsheet);
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, message, subject, {attachments: 
 [liabilityWaiver]}); 
  }}
```

Comment: I guess I wouldn't be surprised at this because Spreadsheets run on the server not on the client.  You'll notice that none of the download types are GOOGLE_SHEETS. I just tried to download a spreadsheet and it was turned into an xlsx file.

Comment: I also looked in my Google Sync directories and all of the Google Docs and Sheets are very small so I'm guessing those are probably just links to the file.

Comment: so how to fix this?

Comment: Just send to some people via script

Comment: There "getAs(MimeType.spreadsheet)" has been "pdf" but I changet it to spreadsheet but it's still don't work...

Comment: What's wrong with just sharing the spreadsheet with whomever you wish?

Comment: Documentation states that pdf is [generally the only option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String)), but it might not hurt to try 'text/csv' or [one of these](https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.html) as a string argument

Comment: You won't be able to do this using just `getAs(MimeType.spreadsheet)`, you need to convert the document to an Excel file. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115383/mail-google-sheet-as-excel-attachment-by-google-apps-script) for the conversion script.

Comment: Do you mind it going to them in google sheets form? If not I'd simply make a copy and then include the text link to that copy in your email, it will show as an "attachment".  Five seconds later programmatically share the file with them. They'll get two emails, one from you and one saying the document was shared with them.